# xil_printf in format %08x is printing out the value: "8x". What's goign on here?

Tags: c, printing, hex, vhdl, xilinx

I'm reading out a 32 bit GPI from VHDL file, and I print it out using xil_printf with format type %08x. For some reason it is printing out 8x, when it normally should print something like 00000003 in hexadecimal format.

```
finishnEnd3 = (0xFFFFFFFF & XIOModule_DiscreteRead(&iom, 3) );

xil_printf("finishnend3 : %08x ,val: %d",finishnEnd3, finishnEnd3);
```

And the output I get are: finishenend3 : 8x ,val: 101187738

Comment: whatever `xil_printf()` is, it's not part of the C standard library. Maybe there's a tag missing to your question, or at least some information what library you are using.

Comment: Please post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. Show the input, the expected output, and the actual output.

Comment: Hopefully, the [tag:xilinx] tag will get this question some attention from people who know about that library. But without code, they probably won't be able to answer it either.

Comment: i added the code now, does it make more sense now ?

Comment: Perhaps you could provide a [mcve]. Your results aren't [casually replicable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajTBb.jpg) (**finishnend3 : 0608009A, val: 101187738**). Include information on the tool chain.

Answer (score 0):

xil_printf only supports a subset of what printf supports. Use sprintf to create a C string then pass it to xil_printf with the %s flag.

```
const int STR_MAX = 100;
int hex = 0xDEADBEEF;
char str[STR_MAX];
sprintf(str, "%08x", hex);
xil_printf("%s",str);
```